# unsupported operands for 'function' and 'int', lambdas are killing me

Tags: python, math, int

I am programming a derivative calculator, and as part of that i have to be able to create funciton representations and then be able to replace variables with numbers and then do the math. im trying to use lambdas to do this for me, but i keep getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'int'`

```
def doit(p):
    a = p.get_base()
    b = p.get_deg()
    return lambda x: a ** b.get_val()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fext = make_pwr('x', 5)
    f = lambda x: doit(fext) + x.get_val()

    print(f(make_const(5)))
```

here is what the const class looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class const(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0.0):
        self.__val__ = val

    def get_val(self):
        return self.__val__

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__val__)

    @staticmethod
    def add(c1, c2):
        assert isinstance(c1, const)
        assert isinstance(c2, const)
        v1, v2 = c1.get_val(), c2.get_val()
        return const(val=(v1 + v2))

    @staticmethod
    def mult(c1, c2):
        assert isinstance(c1, const)
        assert isinstance(c2, const)
        v1, v2 = c1.get_val(), c2.get_val()
        return const(val=(v1 * v2))

    @staticmethod
    def divide(c1, c2):
        assert isinstance(c1, const)
        assert isinstance(c2, const)
        v1, v2 = c1.get_val(), c2.get_val()
        return const(val=(v1 / v2))
```

and the power class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from const import const
class pwr(object):
    def __init__(self, base=None, deg=None):
        self.__base__ = base
        self.__deg__  = deg

    def get_base(self):
        return self.__base__

    def get_deg(self):
        return self.__deg__

    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.__base__) + '^' + str(self.__deg__) + ')'
```

here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Shared/OneDrive/skewl/Spring 2019/CS 3430/hw01/maker.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(f(make_const(5)))
  File "D:/Shared/OneDrive/skewl/Spring 2019/CS 3430/hw01/maker.py", line 37, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: doit(fext) + x.get_val()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

Comment: Please include the code for `make_pwr` and `make_const`

Comment: Please show the traceback. Where is the error happening?

Comment: If I had tof guess, you aren't calling the lambda somewhere.

Comment: ok just added the stacktrace

Comment: @ycx not sure what you mean. the const and pwr class files are there

Comment: what do you mean, not calling the lamba somewhere?

Comment: What is `doit` supposed to be, and why is it returning a function?

Comment: Read the error: you're trying to add a function (the return value of `doit`) and an integer.

Comment: i dont know how to explain. my objective is to take a representation of a function, and basically be able to input a number in as 'x' and it do the math for me. does that make sense?

Comment: Tomothy32 what im trying to do is add the result from the lambda with x.get_val()

Comment: sorry guys, this is literally my first day using python, and my first time using lambdas.

Comment: This looks like a very complicated thing to be trying to write if you're brand new to Python. There's a ton of unpythonic stuff in your code that may be making it harder for you to understand what's going wrong (and making it harder for us to understand what you're intending things to do). For instance, you're inappropriately using `__dunder__` names for your own variables (which should probably just use simple `self.value` names) and *not* using the well defined dunder methods like `__add__` and `__mul__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doit` function returns another function. When you write `doit(fext) + x.get_val()`, you're trying to add that function to something else (an integer as it turns out), which can't possibly work.

It's not really clear to me what the point of `doit` is. It seems to be trying to evaluate an exponential expression, but it doesn't really make any sense, so I can't really fix it for you.

What I *think* you want is to be able to evaluate any given expression, and to be able to transform an expression into its derivative. I think messing around with lambdas and other stuff like that is the wrong way to do that. Instead, you need a more general `Expression` type hierarchy. Something like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Expression(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def eval(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def derivative(self, var):
        pass

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Sum(self, other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Product(self, other)

class Constant(Expression):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self, **kwargs):
        return self.value

    def derivative(self, var):
        return Constant(0)

class Variable(Expression):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def eval(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs[self.name]   # TODO: raise a better exception if the name is not found

    def derivative(self, var):
        if self.name == var:
            return Constant(1)
        return Constant(0)

    def __pow__(self, exponent):
        return SimplePower(self, exponent)

class Sum(Expression):
    def __init__(self, lhs, rhs):
        self.lhs = lhs
        self.rhs = rhs

    def eval(self, **kwargs):
        return self.lhs.eval(**kwargs) + self.rhs.eval(**kwargs)

    def derivative(self, var):
        return self.lhs.derivative(var) + self.rhs.derivative(var)

class Product(Expression):
    def __init__(self, lhs, rhs):
        self.lhs = lhs
        self.rhs = rhs

    def eval(self, **kwargs):
        return self.lhs.eval(**kwargs) * self.rhs.eval(**kwargs)

    def derivative(self, var):
        return self.lhs.derivative(var) * self.rhs + self.rhs.derivative(var) * self.lhs

class SimplePower(Expression):
    def __init__(self, var, exponent):
        self.var = var
        self.exponent = exponent

    def eval(self, **kwargs):
        return self.var.eval(**kwargs) ** self.exponent

    def derivative(self, var):
        if var == self.var.name:
            return Constant(self.exponent) * SimplePower(self.var, self.exponent-1)
        else:
            return Constant(0)
```

Here's a demonstration of it in use:

```
>>> x = Variable('x')
>>> f = x ** 2 + x * Constant(3) + Constant(-2)  # f(x) = x^2 + 3x - 2
>>> f.eval(x=1)
2
>>> f.eval(x=2)
8
>>> f.eval(x=3)
16
>>> f_prime = f.derivative('x')  # f'(x) = 2x + 3
>>> f_prime.eval(x=0)
3
>>> f_prime.eval(x=1)
5
>>> f_prime.eval(x=2)
7
```

Note that because `__pow__` is defined only in `Variable` rather than `Expression`, this code only supports powers of the form `x**c` (where `x` is a `Variable` and `c` is an `int` (not a `Constant`, since we never need to `eval` it)). It does not support powers of arbitrary expressions to arbitrary expressions (which can have very complicated derivatives). Other operations like subtraction and division are not too hard to do, I just omitted them to shorten the code. You could probably also make the `__add__` and `__mul__` operations check for `int` (or maybe `float`) arguments and automatically bundle them up into `Constant`s for you. Then you could write really nice expressions like `f = x**3 + x**2 * 4 + x * -1 + 8` and it would just work (given `x = Variable('x')`).

Comment: thanks a bunch for taking the time to do this! im honestly suprised someone took the time and effort to help me with my problem. thanks a bunch!